# JavaScript toUpperCase() not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a small script that determines whether inputted text is entirely uppercase, entirely lowercase, or neither. Here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function caps (p1){
console.log ("yes");
if (p1.toUpperCase() == p1){
    alert ("Is uppercase")
}
else if (p1.toLowerCase() == p1){
    alert ("Is lowercase")
}
else {
    alert ("Is mix of both");
}
}
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>Write something<br />
      <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input onclick="caps(numero)" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, it doesn't work; the Firefox Web Console insists that "toUpperCase()" is not a valid method. What's happening here?

Comment: I don't think you're passing the selector correctly. In this situation you should be using document.getElementsByName("numero")

Comment: Actually, the variable `numero` will automatically refer to the input element. I think you just want to be passing `numero.value`.

Comment: When in doubt, `console.log(p1);` can be useful to tell what the actual data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onclick`, you call the function like this:  `caps(numero)`

This isn't passing `numero` as a `String`. Its passing it as a variable name. An undefined one. `.toUpperCase` is a method on `String`, and will not exist on `undefined`.

Instead, try: `caps('numero')`

Or, if you're trying to pass the *value* of your text input:

`caps(document.getElementById('numero').value)`

Perhaps better yet, build that into your function:

```
function caps (id) {
    var p1 = document.getElementById(id).value
    if (p1.toUpperCase() == p1){
        alert ("Is uppercase")
    }
    else if (p1.toLowerCase() == p1){
      alert ("Is lowercase")
    }
    else {
      alert ("Is mix of both");
    }
}
```

That way, you can call it like `onclick="caps('numero')"`, passing in the `id` of the input whose value you want to *UpperCase*

Comment: Thanks! It worked! It seems I grossly misunderstood what "weakly typed" means (I am a C# heathen).

Comment: FYI, I realize I was dispensing misinformation above. (I'll edit the answer later). You *can* just pass `numero` as a variable. The DOM auto-magically creates Global variables based on element IDs, so saying `numero` is roughly equivalent to saying `document.getElementById('numero')`. Not sure if this is good practice or if there are any caveats. I would likely go the more verbose path, if only for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, p1 is input element not your input element's value so compare with p1.value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function caps (p1)
{
console.log (p1); //see here 
console.log (p1.value);
if (p1.value.toUpperCase() == p1.value){
    alert ("Is uppercase")
}
else if (p1.value.toLowerCase() == p1.value){
    alert ("Is lowercase")
}
else {
    alert ("Is mix of both");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>Write something<br />
      <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input onclick="caps(numero)" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

not `p1.toUpperCase() == p1`, p1 stand for `input` dom element where id="p1",

don't have `touppercase` method,only string has this method,so you should use p1.value

`document.getElementById(p1)` equals to `p1`,`p1` is the id name

Comment: why my answer is not useful ?